# array that changes length at runtime in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net, how can i declare a array without mentioning size? and it changes the size as the input comes?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s() As String
    ReDim Preserve s(UBound(s) + 1)
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0
    Do

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ")
        s(counter) = Console.ReadLine()
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop Until counter <> -1



    For Each arr In s
        Console.WriteLine(arr)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Based on your description you can't.  You could use a List(Of String) instead of an array.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a List instead of an Array.

```
    Dim s As New List(Of String)
    Dim inp As String
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ")
        inp = Console.ReadLine
        If inp <> "" Then
            s.Add(inp)
        End If
    Loop Until inp = ""

    For Each itm As String In s
        Console.WriteLine(itm)
    Next
```

[List(Of T) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `ReDim Preserve` before **each** name is inserted:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s() As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    Do
        Console.Write("Enter Name (enter `quit` to stop): ")
        response = Console.ReadLine()
        If response.ToLower <> "quit" Then
            ReDim Preserve s(counter)
            s(counter) = response
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Loop While response.tolower <> "quit"

    If counter > 0 Then
        For Each arr In s
            Console.WriteLine(arr)
        Next
    End If

    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer is not wrong but in most cases you should just stick to using a List.

Comment: @Meta-Knight Agreed, nobody actually does it this way.  The only time I really uses arrays is if it is returned to me (like from String.Split()), or if some kind of sub/function requires it...but even then, I start with a List and then call ToArray() against it and pass that.

Comment: Thanks a million... you have been a big help